# Cómo poner hipervínculo en Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

No sé cómo poner un simple enlace en Xamarin.Forms para abrir una página en un navegador. En Android es HiperLink pero en Xamarin no lo sé.

Comment: También puedes verificar este artículo!
https://xamarinhelp.com/hyperlink-in-xamarin-forms-label/

Comment: Buenos días edoman, bienvenido a stackoverflow, te invito a realizar el [tour] y a ver como realizar un [mcve] , trata de ser más específico con la pregunta, ¿Has intentado algo? ¿Dónde tienes el problema?

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con:

```
    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center"
   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Label.FormattedText>
                <FormattedString>
                    <Span Text="Hello " />
                    <Span Text="Click Me!"
              TextColor="Blue"
              TextDecorations="Underline">
                        <Span.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"
                                      CommandParameter="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.GesbDesarrollosTI.cgi" />
                        </Span.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Span>
                    <Span Text=" Some more text." />
                </FormattedString>
            </Label.FormattedText>
        </Label>
```

y a tu código agrégale:

```
 public System.Windows.Input.ICommand ClickCommand => new Command<string>((url) =>
        {
            Launcher.OpenAsync(new System.Uri(url));
        });
```

Es el mismo código del enlace que proporcionó manuelrb98, solo que tenía un componente desactualizado. Saludos

Comment: ¡Evita responder a preguntas que no cumplen con el criterio del sitio! Lee [Como se elabora una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y  [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

No hay ningun control especial para poner hipervinculos.

Lo que tienes que hacer es poner un label, darle el formato que quieras (el subrallado tiene su propia historia) y ponerle control de gestos para que acepte click, y ya ahi abrir una navegacion.

```
<Label Text="Enlace" TextColor="Blue" >
       <Label.GestureRecognizers>
             <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" />
       </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

Si lo que quieres es que se abra el enlace en la aplicación del navegador del movil saliendo de tu aplicación tendras que implementarlo por plataformas. Si no, puedes hacer que se muestre dentro de tu aplicación creando una pagina con control webview.

Comment: ¡Evita responder a preguntas que no cumplen con el criterio del sitio! Lee [Como se elabora una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y  [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).